# How to omit subfolders from node_modules for ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer, angular-json, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

[ngx-extended-pdf-viewer](https://pdfviewer.net/getting-started) allows to omit the subfolders `inline-locale-files` and `additional-locale` after copying the entire library assets

```
 "src/assets",
{
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
  "output": "/assets/"
}
```

I tried to add ignore in the angular.json, but ignore is not allowed.

```
{
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
  "ignore": [
    "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/additional-locale",
    "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/inline-locale-files"
  ],
  "output": "/assets/"
}
```

How can I omit these folders and reduce the language list

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `**/*` by a simple `*`. However, if you need a subfolder, you have to add each subfolder individually. So it's not a nice solution. But it works!

BTW, omitting these folders doesn't have any impact on your runtime performance. It just makes your distribution package smaller.

Comment: could you please clarify more. I have also similar context to make the distribution packages smaller. Thanks!